# Subsurface-Modifier Anvil

Tags: modeling, subsurface-scattering

Hello my fellow Blendercomunity,

I'm using Blender for a week now so I ask you - can you help me? I can't figure out how to get rid of that:

[image]

I tried everything.
To better understand my problem, I give you more screenshots.

[image: Editmode]
[image: From below - Editmode]
[image: From below - Objektmode]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: How much is everything? Please be more specific.

Comment: @moodboots ok, I did. Can you see it?

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter I tried multiple loopcuts or knifes, but I can't put one there. I tried to move the vertexes together (into the mirrored one). Subsurface more or less did nothing. But more than that is above my knowlidge. Thank you

Comment: Have you tried selecting and deleting the face in editmode?

Comment: And by the way it's @moonboots, not moodboots :)

Comment: @BentleyCarpenter You are truely a master of your craft. Thank you. So simple. And yes I knew it's moonboots, I guess I had a grave typo. ^^' By the way, how do I like / vote your answer?